# assembly using nasm "label or instruction expected at start of file"

Tags: assembly

I'm learning how to make a boot-sector and im following all the codes in notepad++ (wine used) and i tried to assemble the code:

```
{BITS 16}
{ORG 0x7C00}

jmp 0x0:Start

Start:
cli
mov AX,0x9000
mov SS,AX
mov SP,0xFB00
sti

mov AH,0Eh
mov AL,'E'
int 10h

cli
hlt

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

i keep getting the error thats up above in the description, and i have no idea how to fix this...

(the code IS spaced properly i dont know why this site put them on the same line like that)

Comment: also i found out like 2 seconds after posting that i used {} instead of [] but the problem still persists

Comment: What line number? I don't see an issue, except for the curly brackets (hippie parentheses - use Republican parentheses or nothing). Are you assembling this in "-f bin" output mode? (it's the only one that knows "org")

Comment: i was using elf, ill give that a try

Comment: same thing...any other ideas?

Comment: "notepad++" giving you unicode instead of ascii? What line number? (Brendan's right about the "user form" being preferred, but it shouldn't make any difference here)

Answer (score 0):

Directives in NASM have a user form (e.g. `bits 16`) and a lower level form (e.g. `[bits 16]`). For a lot of cases they're the same (the user form just gets converted into the lower level form internally). For some cases they aren't the same and the user form does some extra book-keeping stuff that the lower level form doesn't do (e.g. `section` vs `[section]`). In any case, neither of these involve curly braces and you should be using the user form (without square brackets) and not the lower level form (with square brackets).

I don't see any other problems that would cause the error.

I do see a few unrelated problems though (e.g. assuming the EBDA is a specific size, and the `cli` before the `hlt` that prevents "control+alt+delete").

Comment: this is just a tutorial thing on making a boot-sector, not one that actualy works

Comment: i should actually clarify, the code DOES work, well it should. its just not for really making a system.

Comment: Well... there is no such error message in Nasm (AFAIK). The message is "... at start of line". It should be accompanied by the name of the file and the line number where the error occurred. What's it say? I've tried it, and I can confirm what Brendan said. With the curly brackets gone, there is no error in your code. My best guess is that your editor is giving you Unicode or some proprietary "doc" format instead of ascii. See if you can beat it into submission, or if all else fails, try a different editor.

Comment: ok well i tried the ascii thing, and got a new message "nasm: fatal: unable to open input file `boot3.asm'"

Comment: i got it, it turns out the "boot3.asm" file did not exist, i went and checked cause someone said they had the same and to check that out, so i went and opened the other one "boot.asm" changed the "{}" to "[]" and saved it encoded as ASCII, and it worked, so thanks guys for helping with the encoding problem